# Query dynamically with greenDao

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I need to verify some conditions to create a complete query:

> QueryBuilder qb = getMyObjDao().queryBuilder();
>
> if ( someCondition )
>
> ```
>  qb.where(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop1.eq(someValue));
> ```
>
> else
>       qb.whereOr(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop2.eq(someValue),MyObjDao.Properties.Prop2.eq(someValue));
>
> if ( someOtherCondition )
>
> ```
>  qb.where(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop3.eq(someValue));
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
>  qb.whereOr(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop4.eq(someValue));
> ```

So is it possible to concatenate query builder conditions and create query builder dynamically?
or anything so:

> (a = '%'+condition1 or a = '%'+condition1+'%' or a = condition1 + '%') and
>   |(b = '%'+condition2 or b = '%'+condition2+'%' or b = condition2 +
>   '%') and ....

How make that in greenDao?

Comment: This is a complete new question and doesn't seem to be related to greendao. Also your sourcecode isn't clear. Please provide clear sourcecode, that causes your problem and make clear what is source-code and what is log-output and what is your text.

Answer (score 6):

`QueryBuilder.and()` and `QueryBuilder.or()` are used to combine `WhereCondition`s.
The resulting `WhereCondition`s have to be used inside `QueryBuilder.where()` (which will combine the conditions using `AND`) or `QueryBuilder.whereOr()`.

---

Please notice, that all your queries don't make much sense. As consequence the code I give you may not work as you expected, as I am just guessing what you expect.
as example you can take `qb.whereOr(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop2.eq(someValue),MyObjDao.Properties.Prop2.eq(someValue))`

This translates to `where (Prop2 = someValue OR Prop2 = someValue)` or maybe to `where (Prop2 = 'someValue' OR Prop2 = 'someValue')`. In each of them the OR and the second statement are obsolete.

Another example is `(a = '%'+condition1 or a = '%'+condition1+'%' or a = condition1 + '%') and (b = '%'+condition2 or b = '%'+condition2+'%' or b = condition2 + '%') and ....`
If you are not searching for strings with `%` in it, the query with a where-clause like this is going to return none or false results.

---

For:

```
(a = '%'+condition1 or a = '%'+condition1+'%' or a = condition1 + '%') and
(b = '%'+condition2 or b = '%'+condition2+'%' or b = condition2 + '%') and ....
```

You can use something like this:

```
ArrayList<WhereCondition> and = new ArrayList<WhereCondition>();

if (condition1 != null) {
    and.add(queryBuilder.or(
            YourDao.Properties.a.eq("%"+condition1),
            YourDao.Properties.a.eq("%"+condition1+"%"),
            YourDao.Properties.a.eq(condition1+"%")));
}

if (condition2 != null) {
    and.add(queryBuilder.or(
            YourDao.Properties.a.eq("%"+condition2),
            YourDao.Properties.a.eq("%"+condition2+"%"),
            YourDao.Properties.a.eq(condition2+"%")));
}

...

if (and.size() == 1) {
    queryBuilder.where(and.get(0));
} else if (and.size() > 1) {
    WhereCondition first = and.remove(0);
    queryBuilder.where(first, and.toArray(new WhereCondition[and.size()]));
}
```

**UPDATE**

Of course you can use another approach without dynamic list as well:

For:

```
QueryBuilder qb = getMyObjDao().queryBuilder();

if ( someCondition )

 qb.where(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop1.eq(someValue)); 

else
qb.whereOr(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop2.eq(someValue),MyObjDao.Properties.Prop2.eq(someValue));

if ( someOtherCondition )

 qb.where(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop3.eq(someValue)); 

else

 qb.whereOr(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop4.eq(someValue));
```

You can use this:

```
QueryBuilder<MyObj> queryBuilder = getMyObjDao().queryBuilder();
WhereCondition where = null;

if (someCondition1) {
    WhereCondition cond = MyObjDao.Properties.Prop1.eq(someValue);
    if (where == null) {
        where = cond;
    } else {
        where = queryBuilder.and(where, cond);
    }
} else {
    WhereCondition cond = queryBuilder.or(
            MyObjDao.Properties.Prop2.eq(someValue),
            MyObjDao.Properties.Prop2.eq(someOtherValue));
    if (where == null) {
        where = cond;
    } else {
        where = queryBuilder.and(where, cond);
    }
}

if (someOtherCondition) {
    WhereCondition cond = MyObjDao.Properties.Prop3.eq(someValue);
    if (where == null) {
        where = cond;
    } else {
        where = queryBuilder.and(where, cond);
    }
} else {
    WhereCondition cond = MyObjDao.Properties.Prop4.eq(someValue);
    if (where == null) {
        where = cond;
    } else {
        where = queryBuilder.or(where, cond2);
    }
}

List<YourObj> result = queryBuilder.where(where).list();
```

As you see there are a lot of possiblities how you can combine WhereConditions at runtime using greendao. But as long as you don't give a detailed example and description of what you really want to do, nobody can help you.

By the way:

- Using `where()` or `whereOr()` doesn't make any difference, if you are only using one WhereCondition.
- you probably wanted to query: `(a like '%'+condition1 or a like '%'+condition1+'%' or a like condition1 + '%')` instead of `(a = '%'+condition1 or a = '%'+condition1+'%' or a = condition1 + '%')`.
- notice, that `(a like '%'+condition1 or a like '%'+condition1+'%' or a like condition1 + '%')` is equal to `(a like '%'+condition1+'%')` since every result that matches `a like '%'+condition1` or `a like condition1+'%'` will also match `a like '%'+condition1+'%'`.

Comment: So you should ask another question and accept the answer. You asked for a way to concatenate conditions with grrendao: As I said use QueryBuilder.or() and QueryBuilder.and().

Comment: Thanks @AlexS . The approach actually works and it answers the question, despite being verbose. The point is that you have to build the where clause gradually by constructing a {WhereCondition}. You do this by using querybuilder.or, queybuilder.and within your if statements' logic