# Calculate the sum of integer column - GreenDAO Android

Tags: android, greendao

I use GreenDAO library in my Android project, and it works very fine.

This is my table:

```
create table Orders
(
    id int,
    dt date,
    bill int
);
```

Now I am trying to get the sum of whole column after I execute a query on it, like **(select today's orders)** then **(calculate the sum of their bills)**.

The sum of column in SQLite was calculated using this:

```
select sum(bill) from Orders
```

I got the query working in the example below:

[SqlFiddle.com example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0a976/6)

The final query looks like this:

```
select id, dt, bill, (select sum(bill) from Orders) total
from Orders
where id >= 3
```

The GreenDAO generator generated code **OrderDao.java** and **Order.java**

My question is: how to implement the query above in GreenDAO?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably look something like this:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
//look into which Date type to use with GreenDAO's date, I'm not sure if it's
//Date or Calendar or whatever
List orders = orderDao.queryBuilder()
                      .where(Properties.Date == currentDate)
                      .list();
```

This is just a rough sketch, I mean this `Date == Date` part surely needs some fine tuning to work, but this is just the idea on how to make it work. Refer [here](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623523/query-dynamically-with-greendao) to learn how to further refine this.

I hope this helps.

Comment: actually my question is all about combining 2 queries in queryBuilder where i want to get the sum column as extra info that i need

Comment: Can you create 2 queries and combine their results?